# How to find a vector's elevation angle with respect to a point on Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacecraft, low-earth-orbit, frames

**tl;dr:** Spacecraft's antenna should point to a ground station but there is a pointing error. I want to express the error as a vector rather than a simple angle that a dot product provides, so that I can interpret the error in a meaningful way; break it up into components.

They might be along-track vs cross-track errors, or north vs east errors for example.

How can I do this?

Is there a standard way this is done?

---

I have an antenna pointing towards a direction denoted with a vector B. This antenna is on a LEO spacecraft, which has a particular latitude, longitude and altitude. The B vector is making arbitrary angles with the horizontal plane. The antenna sometimes looks downward, sometimes upward and sometimes it points directly west or east. However, what we want is the antenna to look at a specific location on Earth. I am trying to find the difference between where the antenna is looking at and the location it should point at.

I calculate the angle between the antenna pointing vector and the line joining the spacecraft and the location on Earth by using dot product. But this angle does not give me any information if the difference occurs due to the variation in azimuthal direction or vertical direction.

So, I am actually trying to find where the difference comes from. I assume that the spacecraft's look angle (in terms of azimuth and elevation) should be the same as antenna's look angle and azimuth if the antenna is pointing towards the desired location.

I can calculate the azimuth and elevation of the spacecraft with respect to a point (for example a city, for which I know the latitude, longitude and altitude of) on Earth using the point's and the spacecraft's coordinates correctly, and this makes so sense to me: it is very physical. The difference in azimuthal direction is also pretty straightforward. I just calculate the vector's azimuth using the B vector components in x-y plane.

However, I get confused when I have to find what the elevation angle of B vector on the spacecraft is with respect to the selected point on Earth.

The tangent of the B vector's z component and horizontal component sqrt(X^2+Y^2) gives the vector's own elevation angle, but then, how is this angle related with the point on Earth? I think I have to do a conversion there. So, what should be the conversion between the spacecraft's elevation angle and the X vector's elevation angle, then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the elevation angle of B vector on the spacecraft with respect to the selected point on Earth". Do you mean, what the antenna's elevation would be if it was pointing in the same direction from a given point on the Earth's surface?

Comment: I guess what you are referring to in your question is the elevation of the antenna, right? (the angle that the antenna makes with the point on Earth?). I think that would actually be the same as the spacecraft's elevation angle. I rather need to calculate the angle between the antenna's pointing direction with respect to a point on Earth. I have its pointing direction, but not the point on Earth that it is pointing at (the location that sees the antenna on Earth). Because, the antenna's pointing direction keeps on changing. @Litho

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. What is "the angle between the antenna's pointing direction with respect to a point on Earth"? The angle between the antenna's pointing direction and what?

Comment: The angle between the antenna's pointing direction and for example, a city (as a point o Earth): something like latitude, longitude and altitude of New York. I edited the question to be more clear. Thank you for trying to help by the way. :) @Litho

Comment: Do you mean, if the spacecraft had another antenna pointed at the city (or some other given point), what would be the angle between the two antennas? If so, I wouldn't call it "elevation". Elevation is the angle between the direction to something and the horizon. And you're welcome.

Comment: Did you try a cross or dot product between the pointing vector and the vector of the spacecraft to the point on Earth?

Comment: Let's say there are two antennas: first one is on the spacecraft, second one is in New York. My spacecraft should have a specific elevation angle and azimuth for it to be able to point directly at New York. However, my antenna on the spacecraft is looking elsewhere: has a different azimuth and different pointing direction in vertical axis. I solved the azimuth problem, but having problems with its vertical. @Litho

Comment: Are you calculating a vector from the spacecraft to the target point? (i.e. from the spacecraft to New York?)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I calculate the dot product between the antenna direction and the line joining the spacecraft with New York. That gives me the angle between them, but that does not give me the separate differences in azimuthal and vertical directions.

Comment: I edited my post to include this information. Yes, I calculate a vector from the spacecraft to the target point. @OrganicMarble

Comment: So you need the angles in some kind of frame of reference attached to your spacecraft.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly. I am using the North-East-Down frame for my calculations (of all vectors and points). @OrganicMarble

Comment: Usually azimuth and elevation are in relation to something. In this case I'd expect them to be in your spacecraft's frame of reference. But I've been struggling to understand your question the whole time so maybe I'm just confused.  If your spacecraft pitched 90 degrees, would the answer change? If no, I don't know what you are asking, at all.

Comment: Yes, right. I calculate them with respect to N-E-D frame, so that the antenna frame would be the same with the reference frames the city's coordinates are defined in. I understand this is a pretty confusing question. I am confused, too. :) @OrganicMarble

Comment: A sketch showing the vectors you calculate and the angles you need would help a lot.

Comment: @Ceren I've just added a tl;dr to your question at the top. Does that summarize correctly what you'd like to find out how to do? Please feel free to edit further, and *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is a very good summary of the question. @uhoh